# Does the java model require hardware support for single modification order while the c++ model does not?

Tags: java, c++, memory-model

Does the java model require hardware support for single modification order while the c++ model does not?

I write a program with four threads 
t0  sets x = new .. 
t1  sets x = new ..
t2: reads x twice and t3 reads x twice 
can t2 and t3 see the changes to x in different orders?

in c++11 this is a race (result is undefined)
in java it is also a race but there are restrictions on what happens 
for many cpus there is a single -modification order rule- using hardware that forces on of the changes to x to be second to all observers - 
if this is not  supported in hardware and t2 is the garbage collector - does java make any claims?

Comment: Java has its own [Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) independent of the underlying operation system and hardware.

Comment: Java has its own memory model guarantees.  However, if the underlying operating system and hardware have stricter guarantees, Java will often inherit those.  This may sound like a good thing, but it's not, really:  it means that if you program on stricter hardware, things may seem to work fine, but then break when you try to run the program on hardware with fewer guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of explicit synchronization - synchronized blocks, locks, use of atomic variables - t2 and t3 can see the changes in different orders in Java as well as in C++.

Comment: does this give a security hole?

Comment: If programmed improperly, Yes.

Comment: @user2129444 Whether it would be a security hole depends on the exact circumstances.  However, it can and normally should be avoided by the programmer's using the appropriate explicit synchronization.